Do vowels have names?
Do vowels have names used by regular people or academics? For example, the second vowel in student is called schwa. How about the vowel in cat, the vowel in cup, ...?

They don't really have "names". But, for example, the category "Front vowels" in English includes /i/ = Close front unrounded (e.g., "see," "beat"), /ɪ/ = Near-close near-front unrounded (e.g., "sit," "bit"), /e/ or /ɛ/ = Close-mid front unrounded (e.g., "set," "bed"), and /æ/ = Near-open front unrounded (e.g., "cat," "bat"). Plus there are similar subdivisions of Central vowels and Back vowels, as well as diphthong and triphthong combinations thereof.

chatgpt on Typical Distinct Vowel Sounds:
General American English:
Around 14–16 vowel sounds, including monophthongs and diphthongs.
Received Pronunciation (RP, British English):
Around 20 vowel sounds, including monophthongs, diphthongs, and triphthongs.
Other Variants:
    Australian English: Similar to RP, with around 20 vowel sounds.
    Scottish English: Fewer vowels compared to RP, typically around 11–13.
    Southern American English: Often has 12–14 vowel sounds, but with unique distinctions, such as the Southern drawl's effect on diphthongs.


...I always remember how on my first day as an undergraduate in a linguistics class, the lecturer got us 20 students to indicate whether we considered various words to contain "different" vowels. After 5 minutes, I was identified as the student with the lowest number of distinct phonemes, both in terms of what I distinguished on hearing them, and in terms of the actual sounds I made myself. The lecturer said I used the least phonemes of any native Anglophone he'd ever encountered. Less is more, I say - I certainly never had any truck with things like "aspirated" cool wHip.

What research did you do?

English vowels do have names (which are usually more verbose than "schwa").
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_vowels
Close front unrounded vowel
Close front rounded vowel
Close central unrounded vowel
Close central rounded vowel
Close back unrounded vowel
Close back rounded vowel
Near-close front unrounded vowel
Near-close front rounded vowel
Near-close back rounded vowel
Close-mid front unrounded vowel
Close-mid front rounded vowel
Close-mid central unrounded vowel
Close-mid central rounded vowel
Close-mid back unrounded vowel
Close-mid back rounded vowel
Mid central vowel
Open-mid front unrounded vowel
Open-mid front rounded vowel
Open-mid central unrounded vowel
Open-mid central rounded vowel
Open-mid back unrounded vowel
Open-mid back rounded vowel
Near-open front unrounded vowel
Near-open central vowel
Open front unrounded vowel
Open front rounded vowel
Open back unrounded vowel
Open back rounded vowel

It should be noted that these terms are mostly used by language experts. The average person would not be familiar with them. Some may have heard of "schwa" from the question, though.

Sam has provided the precise names, used by linguists or other professionals.  These should probably be considered jargon, because their use outside of linguistics and related academic disciplines is limited.
Non-experts do sometimes need to discuss vowel sounds, most often when teaching spelling to children or second-language learners.  In such cases, there are no firm standards, no strict consensus, but probably the most common convention is the "long vowel/short vowel" terminology.

Long vowels sound the same as their spoken name. For example, the vowel /a/ in bake sounds the same as the letter /a/ in the alphabet...
Examples of long vowel words include:
Long /a/: baby, make, stay
Long /e/: me, we, feet
Long /i/: lion, ice, bike
Long /o/: cold, go, nose
Long /u/: music, unicorn, cube
...
Unlike long vowels that sound more drawn out, short vowels sound quick and concise. Also, they’re typically represented by one vowel letter—for example, /a/ in hat, /e/ in bet, /i/ in bin, /o/ in hop, and /u/ in fun. Short vowels sound as follows:
/a/ sounds like “ah” as in cat, apple, tan 
/e/ sounds like “eh” as in hen, egg, fed 
/i/ sounds like “ih” as in ink, ring, bill 
/o/ sounds like “awe” as in log, fox, rod 
/u/ sounds like “uh” as in ulcer, bug, run

A Preschool Teacher’s Guide to Long Vowels and Short Vowels
This convention seems to work well enough to be useful in teaching English spelling.  But it's certainly not precise.
For example, the word attack would be described as having two "short as".  But we can hear that the first "short a" and the second "short a" do not sound the same.  The first is a "reduced mid central vowel" (a schwa), and the second is a "near-open front unrounded vowel".
If you pronounce energy with two "short es", you'll sound like you have a French accent.
And if "long u" sounds like the letter (/ju/), what do we call the vowel in clue?  And if that u is also a "long u", then is the oo in food a "long u" (it doesn't look like a u)?
When non-experts want to be a little more precise, they tend to use a convention like this:

"a as in hat"
"a as in hard"
"a as in hate"


Yes, but …
Technically, “schwa” is the name of the symbol “ə”, not the name of the vowel it represents. The proper name of that vowel is “mid central unrounded vowel” - which explains by many people, including professional linguists use schwa to mean the vowel rather than the symbol.
But, since “name” just means the label we attach to something, in practical terms schwa is the name of that vowel.
The IPA recognises 20 vowel sounds in English:

Short vowels in the IPA are /ɪ/-pit, /e/-pet, /æ/-pat, /ʌ/-cut, /ʊ/-put, /ɒ/-dog, /ə/-about. Long vowels in the IPA are /i:/-week, /ɑ:/-hard,/ɔ:/-fork,/ɜ:/-heard, /u:/-boot. Diphthong vowels in the IPA are /eɪ/-place, /oʊ/-home, /aʊ/-mouse, /ɪə/-clear, /eə/-care, /ɔɪ/-boy, /aɪ/-find, /ʊə/-tour

Their offical names are descriptive of the place on the vowel chart and whether they are rounded or unrounded. However, unofficial names such as long-o, short-e are used by experts and non-experts alike because who has time for such long-winded names in everyday speech?
These are often coupled with examples, but that’s problematic because English does not have a standard pronunciation and an example that may be correct in one part of the world may be misleading in another. For example, the vowel sound in “cat” is distinctly different between American and Australian English.
